# Applying my function to every position in a Numpy array

Tags: function, numpy, mapping, montecarlo, map-function

I am attempting to apply my CasinoTime function to each position in my array per sweep. The function currently does this but chooses a position at random and can only do one position per sweep. The output looks something like this:

```
Starting Configuration: [[ 1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1]]
0:  [[ 1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1]] Energy: [-2] Spin: 0.2
1:  [[ 1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1]] Energy: [[-10]] Spin: 0.4
2:  [[ 1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1]] Energy: [[-10]] Spin: 0.4
3:  [[-1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 -1]] Energy: [[-2]] Spin: 0.2
```

As you can see, it only alters one position at a time. Ideally my function will run through every position in my array (per sweep) and change the values which meet the criteria. This is a simulation of A Monte Carlo/Metropolis Algorithm. I have attempted to use a map function to apply my function to my array however this does not seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated and I have attached my code below!

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
J = 1
H = 2


def calcEnergy(config, J, H):
    energy = 0
    for i in range(config.size):
        spin = config[i]
        neighbour = config[(i + 1) % N]
        energy = energy - J * (spin * neighbour) - H * neighbour
    return energy


def ChangeInEnergy(J, H, spin, spinleft, spinright):
    dE = 2 * H * spin + 2 * J * spin * (spinleft + spinright)
    return dE


def CasinoTime(sweeps, beta, J, H, debug=False):
    config = np.random.choice([-1, 1], (N, 1))
    averagespins = []

    if debug is True:
        print("Starting Configuration:", (np.transpose(config)))
        runningenergy = calcEnergy(config, J, H)

    for i in range(sweeps):
        spinlocation = np.random.randint(N)
        spin = config[spinlocation]

        spinright = config[(spin + 1) % N]
        spinleft = config[(spin - 1) % N]

        dE = ChangeInEnergy(J, H, spin, spinleft, spinright)

        r = np.random.random()

        if r < min(1, np.exp(-beta * dE)):
            config[spinlocation] *= -1
            runningenergy = runningenergy + dE
        else:
            pass

        averagespin = config.mean()

        if debug and i % 1 == 0:
            print("%i: " % i, np.transpose(config), "Energy:", runningenergy, "Spin:", averagespin)

    return averagespins


averagespins = CasinoTime(sweeps=20, beta=0.1, J=1, H=2, debug=True)
```